# How can I sort an array of sql produced tuples in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sorting

I want to sort an array containing tuples from a sql query based on a particular attribute. I have a table like this:

```
+-----+------------+-----------+
| lid | name       | num       |
+-----+------------+-----------+
|   2 | Ruby's     |         0 |
|   3 | Five Guy's |         1 |
|   4 | Habana's   |         0 |
+-----+------------+-----------+
```

and I want to print out names based on their num attribute AKA I want the output to be:

```
Five Guy's
Ruby's
Habana's
```

I am attempting to accomplish that with this:

```
...
data = cursor.fetchall()
...
def getKey(name):
    return name['num']
sorted(data, key=getKey)
for row in data:
    print row['name']
```

but this outputs the data in the order:

```
Ruby's
Five Guy's
Habana's
```

I'm very to new to python and I am just trying to mess round with some things so please let me know if there are any glaring issues

I am running python=2.7.10

Comment: sorted returns a copy of data.  so you'll need to use data.sort(key = getKey) or data = sorted(data, key=getKey)

Comment: @GarrettR I always do this when asking python questions... thank you!

Comment: You could get rid of the extra function using `operator.attrgetter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for row in sorted(data, key=getKey):
    print row['name']
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `sorted()` returns a new sorted copy of the list. If you want to sort ion place use `data.sort(key=getKey)` (if `data` is a list).You would need to save the return value of `sorted()` to something to use it properly:

```
...
data = cursor.fetchall()
...
def getKey(name):
    return name['num']
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=getKey)
for row in sorted_data:
    print row['name']
```